# I cannot revert my styles.css file to its original form

Tags: php, css, wordpress, file-permissions

I cannot seem to update my **style.css** file found at **[my blog](http://longgame.org/)**. What kills me is that up until a few hours ago, I was able to make incremental changes to the thing (rather than using a child theme).

However, I kept running into problems. For instance, I *had* a background image in the #main-content area. Once I updated the image (keeping the same name), it failed to show. Then I kept fiddling, trying to refine the thing. My problem is that there appears to be **inconsistent behavior** with editing the thing.

And So:

I have attempted to revert the **style.css** *back* to its original form so that I can learn - and use - the whole 'child theme' thing. Problem? I *can't* revert. I've gone into my FTP program, physically deleted the old styles.css file and then copied over the original.

I have refreshed, tried other browsers, cleared the cache within WP, and done everything I can think of. What's more, I've ensured that the code in question...

```
#main-content { background-image: url(gridpaper.gif repeat; padding: 25px; background-color: 0px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)}
```

...includes the fact that I've put the dang 'gridpaper.gif' in a bunch of locations, just in case I'm misunderstanding the url location wrong. I just revisited the site and found that the code I showed above is *not* actually there. My modified version is, which I've been working like mad to *revert.*

I've reviewed the file permissions and can confirm "666" for the *styles.css* file. I'm completely stymied and spent far more time on this than I should have.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: If the style.css stylesheet is cached in your browser, you may want to clear your browser history or hit the reload **button** to refresh the stylesheet.

Comment: I don't see any mention of `gridpaper.gif` here. Try holding shift while reloading.

Comment: please try to change your style-sheet name did this make sense ?

Comment: Okay, so it would appear there was some kind of insane delay, because I did the shift-reload a number of times. The theme is back to normal. Now I need to get the child-theme to somehow work.

Comment: Just for further record on this: I'm wondering if there's some kind of stupid delay in effect. I have successfully activated my child theme (it's pointing to the correct main theme). The lightbulb went off on those relationships... finally. But now I'm waiting for the background image to show up and the main-page subheadings to look more like Impact. Those were my two bits of formatting to test this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the property:

```
background-image: url('gridpaper.gif') repeat;
```